# How can I effectively connect ingame and real life experience

Tags: gm-techniques, roleplaying

I would like to understand how to effectively implement physical techniques in my game where I can blur the lines between what the players and characters are feeling. I'm focused more on physical gimmicks instead of emotional bleed per se. This is also a little different from pure use of props, as the focus is less on a specific prop and more on physical stimuli in general, but it is otherwise similar to the question [What should be considered when deciding if and how to use props?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21811/what-should-be-considered-when-deciding-if-and-how-to-use-props)

Let give me a few examples of implementations of this technique:

1. Four player sitting in a lorry in a big old dwarven mine and drive down in the underground. 
   All players sitting on for chairs (positions like they would sit in a lorry (two in front to behind)). Now the GM says: "A left curve is coming what do you do" Then the players have to lay left or right on there chairs (depending how intelligent or how lucky they are *G). One player has the brake ...
2. You build up a huge dungeon on the table and shut down the light. Every player has a little plate with a snap light stick to see what he rolls. Every player also has a miniature with a snap light stick so he can only see only about 4 fields around his miniature on the map in the dungeon.
3. You build up a city in dense fog and for the fog you put cotton wool on the map. Where the miniatures are you remove the cotton wool

We don't want to play a full on LARP, but I am looking for guidance on the best ways to implement this kind of technique.

Comment: This may be a bit broad as written. It might help if you edit in the way you intend to use this; otherwise, I'm not sure it can be reasonably answered in the generic.

Comment: Is there a specific situation you want to use this for?  Are you trying to understand a certain aspect of tactile interaction?  You'll need to narrow down your question in order for us to be able to provide an answer.